# Can't get JSON in HTTP Request in Android

Tags: java, android, json, http, get

I'm trying to receive a JSON format file throw HTTP in Android. But while i do that i guess the file comes bad formatted. The code is the following:

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                URI website = new URI(params[0]);

                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                request.setURI(website);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("http", e.toString());
            }

            return builder.toString();
        }


@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
                txt.setText((String) jObject.get("shortName"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //txt.setText(result);
        }
```

The JSON file is like this:

```
{"lectiveSemesters":[{"lectiveSemesterId":1,"shortName":"0910i","startYear":2009,"term":1,"termName":"Fall","_links":{"self":"http://thoth.cc.e.ipl.pt/api/v1/lectivesemesters/1","root":"http://thoth.cc.e.ipl.pt/api/v1"}},{"lectiveSemesterId":2,"shortName":"0910v","startYear":2009,"term":2,"termName":"Spring","_links":{"self":"http://thoth.cc.e.ipl.pt/api/v1/lectivesemesters/2","root":"http://thoth.cc.e.ipl.pt/api/v1"}},{"lectiveSemesterId":3,"shortName":"1011i","startYear":2010,"term":1,"termName":"Fall","_links":{"self":"http://thoth.cc.e.ipl.pt/api/v1/lectivesemesters/3","root":"http://thoth.cc.e.ipl.pt/api/v1"}},
...
...
"_links":{"self":"http://thoth.cc.e.ipl.pt/api/v1/lectivesemesters"}}
```

This is just a part of the file.

Am I doing something wrong? I included the header in order to receive in JSON format.

Comment: According your JSON format, the value of lectiveSemesters are an array. so you need to get the JSONArray then for each item in array, you can get value for shortName

Comment: how i do that? with the JSONObject i get JSONArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are. 
       `try{
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jarray = jObject.getJSONArray("lectiveSemesters");
            for(int i = 0; jarray != null & i <  jarray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jitem = (JSONObject) jarray.get(i);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
        }`

Comment: Worked! Understood! Never used JSON so I was a little confuse. Thanks a lot!